# css responsive,sizing and positioning

Tags: html, css, size, positioning

I'm trying to create a responsive website. In the topcontent on the left side of the webpage, i got a picture, on the right side a div with the main content inside it, and underneath the picture a small div with some aditional content. (see link for screenshot http://puu.sh/7VE8p.jpg ) Now what i want to do is to make the maincontent the same height as the photo and the div(under the picture). I know I can do this by setting it in pixels, but then it will be screwed when i want to make it responsive, cuz of the autoheight setting in the picture. I've tried it in % but i couldn't figure it out right.. Here's the code, thanks for your help in advance (I'm a noob :( ).

html:

```
  <div class="content">

                <div class="photo-column" style="height: auto;">

                    <div class="imageBox">
                        <img src="images/rikkertCC.jpg" alt="" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="tekstBallon">
                        <a href="#portolio">

                            <div class="triangle"></div>

                            <div class="tb-cnt">
                                <p>
                                    Meer tekst, en meer tekst, en meer ekst, en meer tekst en meer tekst en meer tekst en meer tekst en meer tekst
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--                <div class="third-column" style="height: 100%">   was 600px, snap niet wrrm de imagecontent hierin stond    
                                </div>-->



                        <div class="tb-cnt-main">
                            <h2>Over ons</h2>
                            <p class="postInfo"> <b>Is dit wel nodig?</b></p>
                            <p>  
                                DiD-Zeeland is een IT-bedrijf die zorgt dat de klant krijgt waar ze 
                                om vragen, voor een betaalbare prijs. Eén van de streven van 
                                DiD-Zeeland, is om een goede naam te krijgen binnen Zeeland 
                                als het gaat om IT-klussen voor de thuisgebruiker, maar ook voor bedrijven.
                            </p>
                        </div>
```

css:

```
    .content {
        width: 80%;
        clear: both;

        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

.photo-column{
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.imageBox {
    height:auto !important;
    max-height: 90%;
    width: 96%;
}
.tekstBallon {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #26a0da;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 16%;

    width: auto;
    max-width: 96%;

    margin-top:3.3%;
}
.triangle{

    position: initial;
    height: 15px;
    width: 25px;    
    margin-left:5%;;



    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);

    background-color:#26a0da;

    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
.tb-cnt-main{
    padding: 3% 4%;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: Segoe ui;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #323232;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
    width: 58.6%;
    float:right;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put all 3 inside another element, you can set your main content's height to 100% of that container. When mixing static height with relative, this is generally the only way to go.

Be sure to choose a display type that will expand to fit content.

Answer (score 0):

So I did not completely look at all of your code because I am in class right now, but if you want to make your site responsive you want to add this code to the END of your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

.classToChange {
  color: red;
}

}
```

So what this will do is IF your screen 568 px width these new css changes will take over.